# By flagging a question can a moderator revise and delete it?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, specific-question, reopen-closed

I am JavaScript developer and create jQuery plugins for other developers. I'm developing a plugin like [`LazyLoad`](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload). I need it to be cross-browser so I asked the following question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13333904/seo-image-index-tag-img-and-tag-a.

Due to the insensitivity of some users who do not understand my good intentions (they thought I wanted to cheat Google-search) I had my question downvoted and closed .

I flagged my own question. Could the downvotes be reversed and can I re-ask my question?

I edited my question, tell me now it is easy to understand? Or still confused?

- If I create another question easier to understand, it may be closed (it will be a duplicate)?
- Or closed questions are not duplicates?
- I was told that SEO is not an issue for the SO. Why then has the tags `SEO` and `seo-friendly`?

Comment: @ben Dammit, 5 secs away from submitting my edit. But glad to see you did an extensive job as well. Thanks. ;)

Comment: I _hate_ it when that happens @bart!

Comment: If only I could +1 an edit...

Comment: At this point (since the question is heavily down voted and deleted), you're best bet is to spend more time composing a more coherent version of it and trying again. Emphasis on _coherent_, and be sure to stay on topic. SEO is not on topic for SO.

Comment: I'm confused, there are the tags SEO and SEO-friendly why? If it is not a matter for the SO, it should not have tags, agree?

Comment: SEO questions should be on web developers exchange

Comment: @TravisJ I already know that the question has more than one year. See http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/seo-index-images-lazyload

Comment: @TravisJ the problem is that I messed up the time because of the 2 tags: "SEO" and "seo-friendly". Do you understand now? Thanks for your -1

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - I was not the downvoter. Someone edited this post and I placed that comment so that anyone thinking about seo can also check on the web developers exchange. Note that after my +1, it is now +3, -1 (2).

Comment: @TravisJ ok, sorry to confusion.

Answer (score 8):

It's hard to understand what you are saying. Your motivations are not as unfavourable to the stake than the way you construct a sentence.

A repeated phrase such as "I ride a LazyLoad" does not make sense.

Unclear English is often a large factor in why a question is closed as "not a real question".

You may flag your question, but a moderator will not and cannot reverse any votes. That is an issue between you and the users who have chosen to vote.

On top of that, asking about what affects SEO is off topic, or not constructive, as the algorithms used by search engines are always evolving in the world of snake oil.

Comment: The LazyLoad will work in with the base HTML structure. Obviously my plugin must work so that does not affect SEO. Ie I need a HTML "accessible" seeker while a page that provides a good experience for the user navigates the page (performance). Sorry for bad English, I would have understood if my motives. Unfortunately the insensitivity of others are the reasons for a question look bad.

Comment: When you need to clarify your question, edit the original to help people understand what you are asking. Do not bury it in the comments. It is less to do with being insensitive and more trying to parse the meaning behind a sentence. The harder you make it for someone to read your question, the less help you get

Comment: The problem is that no one reads, one negative and leave. Note: I've edited. But I'll try to edit again.

Comment: Not enough vomiting zombies committing adultery for it to be a random answer.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - Sorry, it's not that no one reads. I had to read your post 3 times to figure out what your question was. *The question is hidden near the bottom, and looks more like a statement.* I'm not saying that the commenters couldn't have been a bit nicer, because they could have, but you can definitely make your post clearer. You can control what *you* do, but you can't control what *others* do. ;)  Using some formatting, like making the question bold, can help a bit. Good luck!

Comment: @jmort253 Thanks, but I'll stick with the way votes down, closed question and unanswered.

Comment: What makes me sad is not the down votes. It's that I'm with a good intention of creating something good and unfortunately do not know where to get an answer to help me develop.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - No matter where you go, if you don't write a clear question, you are going to have trouble. Unlike the forums, where your question just becomes a random snapshot of the Internet, you can edit your post here and resolve the issues with it. The answer to where to get help to develop is here on Stack Overflow using the most important features on this Q&A platform, the editing feature.

Comment: @jmort253 But I've edited, but nothing worked.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento - I just voted to reopen, you just need 1 more reopen vote. Looking at the revision history, this did turn into a bit of a complicated mess. Good luck!