# Encourage explanatory comments for downvoting new users

Tags: feature-request, reputation, comments, down-votes, new-users

I've had a few friends, predominantly female, downvoted heavily when first using Stack Overflow, and they haven't come back.  To be fair, they were asking bad questions, or asking questions badly; the downvotes aren't wrong.

But the lack of *reason* for the downvotes is off-putting to people just getting started in computer science.  It's not training people to ask better questions; it's training them to look elsewhere, and not growing the service in the way it could.

### Suggestion

*When downvoting a user with fewer than 25 rep*, pop up a message to the downvoter similar to:

> You're downvoting a new user; can you add a friendly comment
>   explaining why, so they can avoid bad questions in the future?

This is explicitly not a duplicate of [canned comments when downvoting new users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143115/canned-comments-when-downvoting-new-users); I'm suggesting special messages when the user who made the initial post is new to the site, not just a generalized canned message when downvoting.

The canned message is already there; when the poster is new at this, give slightly different advice in the canned message.

Comment: It is already suggesting. Making it obligatory doesn't work at all!

Comment: Also, this issue has been raised in meta a lot. You would be getting to many links with just a SE search (Even though SE search is a bit..., you know :)

Comment: @MARamezani: the [list of linked questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/135?lq=1) from the dupe should be required research here, really. 243 posts and counting.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Octuplicate, man! (I wonder if I get that thing's spelling right)

Comment: This feature-request is proposing "users with less than 25 rep popup a specific message" - the question this is duped as is for the standard popup, which is implemented and status-completed. This is a *new* idea entirely.

Comment: possible duplicate of [canned comments when downvoting new users](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143115/canned-comments-when-downvoting-new-users)

Comment: New users being female should be completely irrelevant when voting.  Users being new also has plays no part when voting on content.  Both parts of that argument demonstrate a lack of understanding of what up and downvoting are for.

Comment: @fbueckert New users being female should be irrelevant, but I'm reporting a bug as I see it, if that helps frame this.  The site is losing people it shouldn't be losing.

Comment: @random I've appended rationale to the question of why this isn't a duplicate of the question it's being marked a duplicate of.  Thanks for the link!

Comment: @MARamezani I read the first quarter of the list, fifty questions or so.  None talk about having a threshold; basically, the idea here is to tune the "hey, can you explain your downvote?" when the user posting is very, very new.  I didn't suggest mandatory at all; you did.  Could you, uh, read my post, please?

Comment: @MartijnPieters take a re-read of what I asked, please?  I don't think this is a duplicate, and I've read 50+ of the possible duplicates to check.

Comment: Okay @DeanJ, so, this isn't a dupe. But it doesn't change things much. I can hardly imagine anyone will change their idea of not commenting when they see this pop up. It's just not that *touching* you know. :)

Comment: @DeanJ: Yes, I read what you asked. *The response is still the same*. It doesn't matter that you added a threshold to when the comments are being applied. At issue is that commenting *creates something for that user to focus on* where they should be focusing on improving their post instead.

Comment: On the plus side, whenever I next explain to someone "you'll need Stack Overflow to do your job, but the comments you get on early posts are unfortunately rough or missing your point entirely", I now have an example post of mine to point at.  :-)

Answer (score 7):

This is actually one of the first original ideas for the 'comment when downvoting' concept. While I would never want the mandatory commenting implemented, I like the idea of a suggestion for newish users posts. I would suggest maybe setting the rep level to 11, so if they happened to get two upvotes it would still pop up.

Comment: +1. I'd further suggest removing the [current pop-up notice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/2373) if this is implemented, to avoid "pop-up blindness". If people *only* get a pop-up when the user they're downvoting is new, they're a lot more likely to pay attention to it than if they get one for *every* downvote (as < 2k users currently do).

Comment: @IlmariKaronen, that's a possibly fantastic idea.  (Thank you!)